# how to pass array into function and updates to array are reflected outside function

Tags: arrays, shell, debugging, ubuntu, command-line

I am trying to pass a array into a function and whatever changes made to the array is reflected outside the function

```
function update_array()
{   
    ${1[0]}="abc" # trying to change zero-index array to "abc" , 
                  #  bad substitution error


}

foo=(foo bar)

update_array foo[@]

for i in ${foo[@]}
    do
       echo "$i" # currently changes are not reflected outside the function

    done
```

My questions are

1) How do i access the index array eg: zero index array , in the function , what is the syntax for it

2) How do i make changes to this index array so that the changes are reflected outsite the function also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys by prefixing the var with a `!`:

```
for key in ${!foo[@]}
do
  echo "$key: ${foo[$key]}"
done
```

As for updating the array, you can't pass it to a function, but the function has access to the global state of the script, which means you can do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

function update_array() {
  foo[0]="bar"
}

foo=(foo bar)


for key in ${!foo[@]}
do
  echo "$key: ${foo[$key]}"
done
# 0: foo
# 1: bar

update_array

for key in ${!foo[@]}
do
  echo "$key: ${foo[$key]}"
done
# 0: bar
# 1: bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You function should be defined like this:

```
function update_array() {
    arr=("${!1}")
    arr[0]="abc"
}
```

Then call it as:

```
update_array "foo[@]"
```